# How does a pointer of pointer work in this C code?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int r = 50;
int *p;
int **k;
int ***m;
printf( "r: %d ", r );
p = &r;
k = &p;
m = &k;
***m = 100;  //line 9
printf( "r: %d\n", r );
```

When there is only one pointer, I can understand that we take 100 and we assign it to the variable at the address which is being held by the pointer. But what exactly is happening step by step when we do this with more than one pointer level? (line 9)

Comment: What happened when you tried it, stepping through with your debugger, making notes of varible values at each step?

Comment: @MartinJames first it is 50 and than it is 100. But what is being assigned to what at line 9 i want to know that.

Comment: @MartinJames: Problem is there are too many three-star C-programmers who don't use `***` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int *p=&r`: `p` is a `pointer-to-int`, and it takes the `address of r`.

`int **k=&p`: `k` is a `pointer-to-( pointer-to-int )`, and it takes the `address of p`.

`int ***m=&k`: `m` is a `pointer-to-( pointer-to-( pointer-to-int ) )`, and it takes the `address of k`.

When you do `***m = 100`, you are "unwrapping" the pointers, and finally you end up with just `int`.

Comment: The assignments don't make a variable a pointer. It is its declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The reason pointer-to-pointer works, is that a pointer is a variable, too. It just stores addresses. So a pointer-to-pointer is the address of a variable that contains an address.

[image]

In this diagram `v` is the variable, containing 100. Its address is 1000. `ptr` contains the address of `v`, which is 1000. `pptr` contains the addres of `ptr`, which is 720.

Answer (score -4):

**Pointer to Pointer or Multiline pointer**
When address of `r` is passed to pointer `p`!
Then if you passing the address of `p` to another pointer `k` then for the dereferencing the actual value you want to dereference it two times to get actual value of `r` and so on.

**Take a look at the image**

[image]

Comment: Nice graphic, but why do you have the arrows point *to* the pointers, not from the pointers to their pointed to data? I fear that this might confuse more than it helps.

Comment: because "k=&p ;" in this address of pointer 'p' is passed into pointer 'k' of level 2 !!!

Comment: Yeah ... but pointers *point to* stuff .. just like arrows *point to* .. stuff.

Comment: no , they point to stuff only when they are dereferenced , like **p , **k, ***m will point to stuff r=50 !

Comment: İ think you should invert the arrows too. Because your graphic shows what happens when you assign these variables, not what happens when we execute line 9.

Comment: execution of line 9 is shown , as ***m = 100; ->->-> r=100; in below in image, the arrows are inverted , sorry i draw them from m to r !!!

Comment: I agree with @DanielJour . The arrows in the first diagram should be reversed. That is standard when it comes to pointer diagrams (see linked list or tree diagrams).

Comment: @BhaveshKumar "they point to stuff only when they are dereferenced" **this** is wrong. `int x = 42; int * y = &x;` in this code snippet `y` points to `x`, even if it's never dereferenced.

Comment: "they point to stuff only when they are dereferenced" , by it I mean the values stored in their memory addresses ! and not their dereferencing value !!! @DanielJour

Comment: @BhaveshKumar: Oh, I have. And going personal does not change you are wrong here.

Comment: @Olaf Nothing is personal Mr. Olaf, I said what I have read !